# Power of Silver Fang (Bang)

Tags: one-punch-man

I was watching the anime and I noticed in the episode where the meteorite was about to hit earth, Silver Fang or Bang still standing beside Genos. As far as the animated serial goes, just before Saitama is about to enter the scene, Bang's expression changes slightly as if he is about to do something.

Also, in some later episode, he hypothesizes what would have happened if he used the fist of flowing water on the meteorite? How much exactly is Bang's power and could he had destroyed the meteor?

Comment: To compare any character with Saitama is pointless. And to give a measure of the power level Bang has, it would mean manga spoilers and opinions..

Comment: @EroSɘnnin  Actually, Bang defeated Saitama in Stone paper scissor.

Comment: @DuttaA He won that because of technique and prediction. The writers used that scene to show how experienced bang is. His flowing water technique enabled him to win every time **despite** the overwhelming difference in power/speed, this scene should not be used as a basis for comparing their power as it was used to show how power and speed is the only thing Saitama has which was not enough here

Comment: @DuttaA: you're saying that could be used as a point of comparison of power level? It seems quite unrelated to the question at hand.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin i just am speculating bang's power just like people speculate saitama's power

Comment: @DuttaA: with his stone paper scissors game skill?

Comment: @EroSɘnnin most ppl got my question wrong..i am not asking for saitama's power to be compared with bang...i am just asking bang's power ....like whether he could have destroyed the meteorite..defeated sea king, etc

Answer (score 4):

Well if you're trying to compare Saitama and Bang's power it's pointless. In one of the specials when Saitama goes to his Dojo, Bang admits himself that Saitama is way more powerful. Plus we don't know the limitations of Saitama's power. On the other hand, he's very likely stronger than Genos based on the fact that he's rank 3 in the S class of Heros and his experience and technique. Also if you watch the last episode where the S class Heros fight the monster, Bang seemed to be slightly stronger and fair slightly better than the other Heros like Atomic Samurai.

I'd say Bang is very likely stronger than all the S class Hero's below his ranking. However, Tatsumaki appears to be stronger than him.